# Discrete random variables - derivation of the expected value E[g(X)] of a function g(X)

Tags: probability, probability-theory, random-variables

[Mathematical derivation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h5hpg.png)

The derivation is shown above but I am wondering why the need for the two summation signs? I understand we are finding the sum of the PMF of x such that g(x) = y but why do we need the other?

If anyone could explain the intuition that would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because
$$p_Y(y) = P(Y=y) = P(g(X)=y) = \sum_{x \text{ s.t. } g(x)=y} P(X=x)=\sum_{x \text{ s.t. } g(x)=y} p_X(x)$$
This sum on the right is then substituted for $P_Y(y)$ in the formula
$$E[Y] = \sum_{y} y p_Y(y).$$

Comment: The second to last line, how do the two summation signs dissappear to form just one?

Comment: Every $x$ has $g(x)=y$ for some (unique) $y$, and so every $x$ will show up in the sum exactly once.